# debug javascript code under test running in the browser using zuul

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browserify, minify, zuul-testing

1. I've written a javascript component, let's say in file
   `component.js`
2. I've written some tests, let's say in file `test-component.js` that verify the DOM manipulation that happens in the component.  It uses a `require('./component.js')` statement to load the code under test.
3. I'm using [zuul](https://github.com/defunctzombie/zuul) to run the tests in a local browser.
   The command is similar to:

   `zuul --local 8080 --ui mocha-tdd -- src/test/js/test-component.js`
4. I'm browsing to `http://localhost:8080/__zuul` using Chrome with Developer Tools (F12) open.
5. I can debug the test code in `test-component.js` using Chrome (it shows in the same format as in my IDE)

Now my issue: when I open `component.js` in Chrome Developer Tools, the code shows minified (not obfuscated though).  Chrome can pretty-print this minified file, but then you can't add breakpoints and even then there is a line inserted between almost every two lines of code, looking like this:

```
__cov_CgRFa1QfsDvBYUENO9jTSQ.s['119']++;
```

I'm pretty sure this is for gathering the test coverage information.  But this makes it hard to read the code.  Is there a way to run zuul without the minification and the code transformation that adds the statements for code coverage?

Comment: there is no test running in the browser.   there is only zuul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zuul Github wiki instruct to turn off coverage with --no-coverage

https://github.com/defunctzombie/zuul/wiki/debugging-zuul